Why does my window function seem to use the entire data set?
I have this query but the max and avg don't seem to work as expected:
SELECT 
    UPPER(SUBSTR(first_query.periodname, 1,3)) AS month,
    ROUND(first_query.amount) AS amount,
    ROUND(MAX(first_query.amount) OVER (ORDER BY first_query.postingPeriod ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING)) AS maxamount,
    ROUND(AVG(first_query.amount) OVER (ORDER BY first_query.postingPeriod ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING)) AS avgamount,
    ROUND(LAG(first_query.amount) OVER (ORDER BY first_query.postingPeriod)) AS lagamount,
    ROUND(LEAD(first_query.amount) OVER (ORDER BY first_query.postingPeriod)) AS leadamount
FROM (
    SELECT
        SUM(tl.foreignamount * t.ExchangeRate * -1) AS amount,
        BUILTIN.DF(t.postingPeriod) AS periodname,
        t.postingPeriod
    FROM
        Transaction t
    JOIN transactionline tl ON t.id = tl.transaction
    JOIN account a ON a.id = tl.expenseaccount
    WHERE
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.trandate) = 2023  
    GROUP BY
        BUILTIN.DF(t.postingPeriod),
        t.postingPeriod
    ORDER BY
        t.postingPeriod
) AS first_query
ORDER BY
    first_query.postingPeriod;

It results in:



month
amount
maxamount
avgamount
lagamount
leadamount




JAN
1833916
1833916
1833916
null
1857884


FEB
1857884
1857884
1845900
1833916
2048416


MAR
2048416
2048416
1913405
1857884
1731385


APR
1731385
2048416
1867900
2048416
1543348


MAY
1543348
2048416
1802990
1731385
1642432


JUN
1642432
2048416
1776230
1543348
1541351


JUL
1541351
2048416
1742676
1642432
1862392


AUG
1862392
2048416
1757640
1541351
1377795


SEP
1377795
2048416
1715435
1862392
1324765


OCT
1324765
2048416
1676368
1377795
1042649


NOV
1042649
2048416
1618758
1324765
1365764


DEC
1365764
2048416
1597675
1042649
null



So you can see the lag and lead work great, however it is easy to see the max doesn't work. It just keeps adding the new row into the window from what I can tell.
Any ideas on what I'm missing? Thanks!

Your MAX() window function's frame specification is ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 0 FOLLOWING. So the only row that is considered is the current row. Doesn't this make the call to MAX() redundant?

oh sorry, I pasted what I was testing. It is actually 1 and 1. I'll update my post

What data are you expecting exactly?

Can we have sample input data for all tables so we can try your query?

@Bohemian I am trying to get the average amount for each month plus the month before and after. So Jan would be average of JAN & FEB. Feb would be average of JAN, FEB, MAR and so on. I included the max column to see if it would help me understand what is going on and it looks like it is ignoring the window.

Not exactly sure what was wrong with the window function, but found a work around using rownum and WITH subqueries. Pretty messy but at least it's working.
WITH first_query AS (
    SELECT
        t.postingPeriod AS postingperiod,
        BUILTIN.DF(t.postingPeriod) AS periodname,
        SUM(tl.foreignamount * t.ExchangeRate * -1) AS amount
    FROM
        Transaction t
    JOIN
        TransactionLine tl ON t.id = tl.transaction
    WHERE
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t.trandate) = 2023
    GROUP BY
        t.postingPeriod,
        BUILTIN.DF(t.postingPeriod)
),
second_query AS (
    SELECT
        rownum,
        postingperiod,
        periodname,
        ROUND(amount) AS amount
    FROM
        first_query
),
final_query AS (
    SELECT 
        rownum,
        postingperiod,
        periodname,
        amount,
        (SELECT MAX(sq.amount) 
         FROM second_query sq
         WHERE sq.rownum BETWEEN second_query.rownum - 1 AND second_query.rownum + 1) AS max_amount,
        (SELECT AVG(sq.amount) 
         FROM second_query sq
         WHERE sq.rownum BETWEEN second_query.rownum - 1 AND second_query.rownum + 1) AS avg_amount
    FROM 
        second_query
)
SELECT 
    UPPER(SUBSTR(periodname, 1, 3)) AS month,
    ROUND(amount) AS amount,
    ROUND(max_amount) AS maxamount,
    ROUND(avg_amount) AS avgamount
FROM 
    final_query
ORDER BY 
    postingperiod;

